# <com.chaos.view.PinView this is show nothing for me

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.4'
when i try to call it on my layout
it show nothing

```
 <com.chaos.view.PinView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

this is my layout code

i already try 1.4.2 , 1.4.3 version and still the same, its show a underline strip

and i already try using another pinview like otpview, and still show a underline strip

[its show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WLMd.png)

[and this is my dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzx0Y.png)

[This is what i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODP26.png)

Answer (score 3):

In my case **I solved** this issue by replaced it.

you should replace this implementation:

```
implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.4'
```

**✓** to this implementation **✓** :

```
implementation 'io.github.chaosleung:pinview:1.4.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem but as soon as I implemented the dependency at the top it worked for me..

[image]

You can try to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't seeing any blocks is you haven't added the item count which defines the number of values you pin-view contains. Below is the code that can help you view the pin-view properly in your application.

```
<com.chaos.view.PinView
    android:id="@+id/firstPinView"
    style="@style/PinWidget.PinView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:hint="Hint."
    android:inputType="text"
    android:itemBackground="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="@dimen/common_padding"
    android:textColor="@color/text_colors"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:cursorColor="@color/line_selected"
    app:cursorWidth="2dp"
    app:hideLineWhenFilled="true"
    app:itemCount="5"    //The required line
    app:itemHeight="48dp"
    app:itemRadius="4dp"
    app:itemSpacing="0dp"
    app:itemWidth="48dp"
    app:lineColor="@color/line_colors"
    app:lineWidth="2dp"
    app:viewType="rectangle" />
```

**PS:** If you can't see the pin item in your android studio but you can see it in the app then build the Gradle again and you can see the pin blocks in your studio

Comment: already done it all, and still cannot, i already try to deleete the .androidstudio file to check if the setting goes wrong

Comment: i already try using 1.4.2, 1.4.3, and 1.4.4 still doesnt come out even when i put itemcount  @CodeREDInnovations

Comment: Have you tried it in emulator or real-time device?. Does the blocks aren't appeared in you device too?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to reply, but I was facing the same issue.

It worked for me after I rebuilt my project following these steps:

`Build` -> `Make Project`

Shortcut for that would be by default:

`Ctrl+F9`